# Select a specific Date within a Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

i am currently facing a problem where i can't get the correct solution for.

I made a measure with the running summation of a percentage Value in PowerBI. It's for every Country the percentage of sales made daily last year compared to the total value of the month.

Now i am trying to get only the value from the current day from the measure.

[Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk6lD.png)

I tried it with lookupvalue but it seems like it is not working with measures.

Pls help me ...

Comment: The question is very unclear, therefore so will be this comment. Have you tried `CALCULATE([Your measure], FILTER(TableWithDate, TableWithDate[Date] = SELECTEDVALUE(TableWithDate[Date]))`?

Comment: I am trying to get the specific column from the table which shows the current day of the month. Therefore i tried it like this: CALCULATE(F_Retail[Running sum von %%Vert in Tag];'Dim_Datum (3)'[DATUM] == DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1;MONTH(TODAY());DAY(TODAY())))
(The -1 is because i use values from last year). But the only number i get back is a 1.

Comment: For example : It is the 5th of February so i only get the column for the 5th Day.